# Update controllers in AngularJS with Services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controllers

**I ask for excuse for my bad english!!**

Hello, I've a problem:

```js
var app = angular.module('testino', []);


app.controller('listController', listController );

listController.$inject = ['service'];

function listController(service) {
  console.log("listController instanziato");
  
  vm = this;
  vm.lista = service.getLista();
  

  vm.add = function () {
    service.addElement();
    service.getLista;
  }



  vm.load = service.load();

}

app.controller('loadingController', loadingController);
loadingController.$inject = ['service'];

function loadingController (service) {
  console.log("loadingController instanziato");

  var vm = this;
  vm.load = service.load();

 

}



app.factory('service', service);
service.$inject = ['$http'];

function service ($http) {
  console.log("service instanziato");

  var sv = this;
  sv.lista = [ {1:"ciao"},{2:"ciao"},{3:"ciao"}];
  sv.load = "LOADING"

  return  {
    getLista : getLista,
    addElement : addElement,
    load : getLoading
  }
  
  function getLista() {
    return sv.lista;
  }

  function addElement() {
    sv.lista.push( {ciao:4} );
    console.log (sv.load);
    sv.load = "LOADED";    
    console.log (sv.load);
  }


  function getLoading () {
    return sv.load ;
  }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="testino">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
  
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="loadingController as vm">loading: {{vm.load}} </div>

  <ul ng-controller="listController as lvm">
    <button ng-click='lvm.add()'>Ciccio</button>
    <li ng-repeat = "e in lvm.lista">{{e}}  </li>

    <li>Caricamento: {{lvm.load}}</li>
    <input type='text' ng-model='lvm.load' />
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

When I try to push (or pop) elments in array (sv.lista - service), all it work but the varible "vm.load" on listController and on loadingController, it's not updated..

I wanna take data on service and to update the controllers just updating data on services.

How can I do?

Thaks!!

Comment: This article very clearly explains binding to references http://stsc3000.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/a-tale-of-frankenstein-and-binding-to-service-values-in-angular-dot-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the loading status as an object. Right now you return the loading status when the controllers start as a string, and then when the status changes, you can't see any update because you lost the reference when you changed the string. With objects, you can keep multiple references to the same object and everyone can see when that object changes.

```js
var app = angular.module('testino', []);


app.controller('listController', listController );

listController.$inject = ['service'];

function listController(service) {
  console.log("listController instanziato");
  
  vm = this;
  vm.lista = service.getLista();
  

  vm.add = function () {
    service.addElement();
    vm.load = service.load();
  }



  vm.load = service.load();

}

app.controller('loadingController', loadingController);
loadingController.$inject = ['service'];

function loadingController (service) {
  console.log("loadingController instanziato");

  var vm = this;
  vm.load = service.load();

 

}



app.factory('service', service);
service.$inject = ['$http'];

function service ($http) {
  console.log("service instanziato");

  var sv = this;
  sv.lista = [ {1:"ciao"},{2:"ciao"},{3:"ciao"}];
  sv.load = "LOADING";
  sv.loadObj = { status: sv.load };

  return  {
    getLista : getLista,
    addElement : addElement,
    load : getLoading
  }
  
  function getLista() {
    return sv.lista;
  }

  function addElement() {
    sv.lista.push( {ciao:4} );
    console.log (sv.loadObj.status);
    sv.loadObj.status = "LOADED";    
    console.log (sv.loadObj.status);
  }


  function getLoading () {
    return sv.loadObj ;
  }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="testino">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
  
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="loadingController as vm">loading: {{vm.load.status}} </div>

  <ul ng-controller="listController as lvm">
    <button ng-click='lvm.add()'>Ciccio</button>
    <li ng-repeat = "e in lvm.lista">{{e}}  </li>

    <li>Caricamento: {{lvm.load}}</li>
    <input type='text' ng-model='lvm.load.status' />
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```